# Create a dictionary that has summary value from list / Combine two different dictionaries to summarize value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am new to python and working with dictionaries and list. 
Here is the list

```
detail = [(1, [u'apple', u'2017-07-03T08:03:32Z', 'boston']),


 (2, [u'orange', u'2017-07-03T08:58:35Z', 'NOLOCATION']),


 (3, [u'grape', u'2017-07-03T12:14:12Z', 'boston']),


 (4, [u'cherry', u'2017-07-04T13:16:44Z', 'new york']),


 (5, [u'strawberry', u'2017-07-06T10:56:22Z', 'san francisco']),


 (6, [u'plum', u'2017-07-06T10:56:22Z', 'seattle'])]
```

I want to summarize this, so that - for each date, I get split of counts for each location. Something  like this -

```
details_summary = {'2017-07-03':[(boston,2), (NOLOCATION,1)], '2017-07-04':
[new york,1], '2017-07-06':[(san francisco,1),(seattle,1)]}
```

I want it in this format, because I want to generate map (visualization) for each date (key), and location points(value).

I ended up creating two different dictionaries that look like this -

```
location = {u'boston': 2, 'NOLOCATION': 1, u'new york': 1, u'san francisco': 
1, u'seattle': 1} 

date = {'2017-07-03':3, '2017-07-04':1, '2017-07-06':2}
```

Now, I want to summarize so that I get, split of counts in different location for each date and I am stuck here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
d = {}
for k, (w, t, l) in detail:
    date = t.split('T')[0] # you can choose to enhance date "isolation"
    if date in d:
        d[date].append(l)
    else:
        d[date] = [l]
details_summary = {k: Counter(d[k]).items() for k in d.keys()}
```

Comment: This returns **'int' object is not iterable** error at line 2. (for k, (w, t, l) in detail:)

Comment: @Newbie place a `print(detail)` before the offending loop to check the value of the `detail` variable. Maybe you have accidentally overwritten it with an `int`?

Comment: Ok.. but I want the count (number of occurrences) of Boston, New york etc and not their key.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of Python collections `defaultdict` and `Counter`

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
summary = defaultdict(list)
for item in detail:
  summary[item[1][1].split('T')[0]].append(item[1][2])

details_summary = {str(k):[(x,y) for x,y in Counter(v).iteritems()] for k,v in summary.iteritems()}
print details_summary
{'2017-07-06': [('san francisco', 1), ('seattle', 1)], '2017-07-04': [('new york', 1)], '2017-07-03': [('boston', 2), ('NOLOCATION', 1)]}
```